# $X_n \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_n)$, independent, $\sum 1/\lambda_n = \infty$, then, $\sum X_n=\infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent Exponential random variables with mean
$$
E(X_n)=\frac{1}{\lambda_n},
$$
where
$$
0 < \lambda_n < \infty.
$$
If
$$
\sum \frac{1}{\lambda_n} = \infty,
$$
show
$$
P\left(\sum X_n = \infty\right) = 1.
$$

It looks like a job for the Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I don't see which sequence of events will give the result.

Let
$$
X=\sum X_n,
$$
then
$$
\sum \frac{1}{\lambda_n}=E(X) \ge \sum P(X>n),
$$
but this is in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The event $\sum_j X_j=\infty$ is a tail event, hence its probability is $0$ or $1$.
2. Assume it is $0$; then the series $\sum_j X_j$ is almost surely convergent, hence it is supposed to converge in law.
3. Computing the characteristic function of partial sums, and in particular their modulus, one can see this can't happen.

Comment: Whoa! Of very great level. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.